# Code-behind properties inaccessible at design time but do work properly at runtime

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have to make some changes to a legacy ASP.NET website. It has a Property declaration like this:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Foo As String
    Get
        If Not Session("Foo") Is Nothing Then
           Return Session("Foo").ToString()
        Else
           Return ""
        End If
    End Get
End Property
```

At design-time, looking at some javascript on the markup page, the property is inaccessible, *although it works properly at run-time*. That wrinkle makes this question a little different from others like it which have been asked here.

```
  var f = <%= Foo %>;
```

In the Visual Studio editor, `Foo` is underlined in red; the error shown in the tooltip: `Foo is undeclared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level`.

All of the properties on the page are inaccessible, not just this one.

What could be causing that spurious error at design-time?

EDIT: Here's some new info:

On an object declaration on the page, I am getting this error:

**Private WithEvents MyGizmo as Gizmo**

```
Class MyAssemblyName.Gizmo
   MyAssemblyName -- Not Available
   MyAssemblyName -- Available
```

I do not understand it.  `MyAssemblyName` is mentioned twice, once as not available and once as available.

END OF NEW INFO

I've checked the page declaration:

`MyAssemblyName` matches the assembly  name and the root namespace as shown on the **Project Properties** page.

The application type is **Class Library**.

I've checked the class declaration for protection level:

```
Public Class Widgets

End Class
```

and have made sure that the Web Form Designer Generated Code is present:

```
#Region " Web Form Designer Generated Code "

    'This call is required by the Web Form Designer.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> Private Sub InitializeComponent()

    End Sub

    'NOTE: The following placeholder declaration is required by the Web Form Designer.
    'Do not delete or move it.
    Private designerPlaceholderDeclaration As System.Object

    Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Init
        'CODEGEN: This method call is required by the Web Form Designer
        'Do not modify it using the code editor.
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

#End Region
```

What else to check?

Comment: Are you sure the project is even compiling? Try clean and rebuild. What framework version is that legacy application? Is it an old web site -style project?

Comment: A Clean and Rebuild All both report 1 succeeded 0 failed 0 skipped. It is now targeting 4.5  I am going through the code and checking Namespace declarations now.